# ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions update with uses-feature in Ionic mobile application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently received a notification from Google asking to update the way we declare the use of native geolocation in-app.

In Ionic (v1), cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.3.0 "Geolocation" installed.
Line declared in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Google is telling us to use instead :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

- Is there any clean way to insert it into the AndroidManifest.xml ?
- Should it be with a hook ?
- Should I wait cordova-plugin-geolocation to update the plugin in order to satisfy Google recommandations ?

Comment: if you are reffering to `Google Play change to Android ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions` email. My understanding was that you Don't need to do anything. If your required is false. It needs adding to apps if required is True.

Comment: Actually, my app can work without geolocation but it improve considerably user experience. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#required says that maybe I should write android:required="true", shouldn't I ?

Comment: If it's not required then is fine without it. If you want them to definitely have it so they do not experience this lesser user experience, then add it true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify android manifest properties from the config.xml file like this:

```
<platform name="android">
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false">
</config-file>
</platform>
```

Also if you are getting the `unbound prefix's` error, put `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` at the top of your config.xml file

For example:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id        = "com.akis.android"
        version   = "0.1"
```

Comment: I tried it : AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
config-file doesn't seem to exist in config.xml cordova reference.

Comment: @littleboy updated my answer, dont forget to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in your config.xml. it goes at the top of the file

Comment: It's working when I don't specify the attribute "parent" (parent="/manifest"). If it seems necessary for you to update your answer, i'll let you do it before giving you the upvote !
Thank you.

Comment: @Akis I still can't see <uses-feature> tag in AndroidManifest.xml file after I run 'cordova build android'.

Answer (score 2):

The cordova-plugin-geolocation plugin has now been updated so updating to version 2.4.0 should include this requirement.